# Bootstrap 4 client validation before ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, bootstrap-4

I have a form (see it below). We follow bootstrap 4 on a project therefore I prefer to re-use as much as possible and do not write my own code where it is not needed.

When user press Submit button I do AJAX post request and as a response I get JSON object with some information. Based on that response I have to do some logic.

```
<form name="signin" class="js-form-submit needs-validation" action="/signin">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">User Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" >
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit/button>
</form>
```

Now I want to make client-side validation (and I prefer to use bootstrap if possible). They have an example but it works with normal submit but not with AJAX and I'm curious how can I perform bootstrap 4 client-side validation before my AJAX call?

```
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#custom-styles

Could somebody point me on a direction or maybe give a snippet of code.

Thanks.

Comment: I added a smiliar question with more details. I'm also trying to achieve this, but also having trouble, because there is another pitfall with the Bootstrap validation, when you put your XHR call in the else statement... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71286771/how-to-properly-use-xmlhttprequest-with-bootstrap-5-client-validation-via-java

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution using JQuery. Try this code,

```
$('your-form-id').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('your-form-id')[0].checkValidity() === false) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        //do your ajax submition here
    }
    $('your-form-id').addClass('was-validated');
});
```

Comment: I think that is not tested. This snippet could call submit and ajax call also.

Comment: Works fine, just tested it with a bootstrap 4 form layout.

Answer (score 3):

Add your ajax request to the else condition statement, this will do it.

```
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
            }else {
               //do your ajax submition here
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
          }, false);
        });
      }, false);
    })();
```

Comment: this code assumes that the ajax completes ok and so the modal form is dismissed when you may actually need to change some data and submit again.